# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading in sbt project with sbt plugin module

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module

I'm having the following problem. I have a multimodule project described in the following way.

```
import Build._
import sbt.Keys.scalacOptions

lazy val moduleA =
  module(id = "module-a", "module-a")

lazy val moduleB =
  module(id = "module-b", "module-b")

lazy val root =
  module(id = "sample-project", directory = ".")
    .aggregate(moduleA, moduleB)

lazy val plugin = Project(id = "plugin", base = file("plugin"))
  .settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    name := "MyPlugin"
  )
  .dependsOn(moduleA)
```

Where `Build` declares the following helpers

```
object Build {
  val scala212 = "2.12.11"
  val scala213 = "2.13.3"
  val projectScalaVersion = scala213
  val supportedScalaVersions = List(scala213, scala212)

  val projectVersion = "0.3.5-SNAPSHOT"
  val projectOrganization = "com.example"

  val commonSettings = Seq(
    version := projectVersion,
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
    organization := projectOrganization,
    scalaVersion := projectScalaVersion,
    scalacOptions += "-deprecation",
    scalafmtOnCompile := true
  )

  def module(id: String, directory: String): Project = {
    Project(id = id, base = file(directory))
      .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  }

  implicit class ProjectOps(project: Project) {
    def libraries(modules: ModuleID*): Project = {
      project.settings(libraryDependencies ++= modules)
    }

    def disablePublish: Project = {
      project.settings(publishLocal := {}, publishM2 := {}, publish := {})
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add an sbt plugin to expose some of the parts of the project using tasks.
Unfortunately when compiling the plugin I get the following error:

```
sbt:sample-project> plugin/compile
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last plugin / update for the full output
[error] (plugin / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.example:module-a_2.12:0.3.5-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/example/module-a_2.12/0.3.5-SNAPSHOT/module-a_2.12-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/ltrojanowski/.ivy2/local/com.example/module-a_2.12/0.3.5-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.example/module-a_2.12/0.3.5-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.example/module-a_2.12/0.3.5-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 26, 2020 1:35:20 PM
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any help or tip in how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this. Sbt plugins for version 1.x have to be built using scala 2.12. But it would still be nice to have a regular compile of the plugin trigger the compilation of the dependent modules with scalaVersion 2.12